# Infinite Sets Constructions from Category theoretic foundation

Tags: category-theory, set-theory

Cantor developed arithmetic of infinite sets with cardinals and ordinals.In category theory, the cardinal numbers form a skeleton of the category of sets. What are the category-theoretic foundation for these constructions ?  Any references to analyze them systematically ?

Comment: Taking skeletons pretty much goes against the "spirit of category theory". Being a skeleton is an [evil](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/principle+of+equivalence) property, so it is not really something you would want to study categorically.

Comment: I don't think I understand the question; you seem to have pretty much answered it yourself. What more do you want beyond the realization that cardinals are isomorphism classes of sets?